# Flash AS3, getting text from Input Field

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Getting back into AS3 and have become stuck using a textinput, when I trace the text variable the output window is showing it as null?

The variable is called stext:String and the capture text function is returning a null?

```
package  {
//Import Statements
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class MyAppMain extends MovieClip {

    /* --------------
    DECLARE VARIABLES
    ---------------*/
    var search:MovieClip;
    var searchText:MovieClip;
    var stext:String;



    public function MyAppMain() {
        // constructor code

        loadSearch();               //CALL LOADSEARCH FUNCTION
    }

    function loadSearch(){
        //LOAD SEARCH BUTTON
        search = new Search_btn;
        search.x = 10;
        search.y = 10;
        search.buttonMode = true;
        addChild(search);
        search.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, test);

        //LOAD TEXT AREA
        searchText = new SearchText_txt;
        searchText.x = 10;
        searchText.y = 50;
        addChild(searchText);

    }

    function test(e:MouseEvent):void{
        captureText();
        trace ("I have arrived at test")

    }
    function captureText():void{
        stext = searchText.text;
        trace ("Answer" +stext);
    }




}
```

}

Comment: searchText is not an inputText and has no such property as text so it always come back null. You have put this movieclip together yourself so you should know how to reference the inputtext you put inside of it.

Comment: What is SearchText_txt? Why are you trying to create a new instance of it, without parenthesis?

Comment: this is obviously a library MC and parenthesis are not required in AS3 if no parameters are required.

Comment: It's very likely gonna be something like searchText.theinputtext.text

Comment: Should I not define the input text field as a movieclip, is this a bad practice?

Comment: It's a little confusing. It the variable is of type "SearchText_txt" you should declare it as such. This is easier to read, and is the only way that most IDEs will understand object type for code completion and syntax checking.

Regardless, it seems that you have declared a Library class of SearchText_txt, is this a MovieClip that contains a TextField?

Comment: That seems likely that he converted a textfield into a library MC, in that case the object is a MC that contains a textfield. That etxtfield should have a name and be referenced by dot notation with that name.

Comment: I understand you #BotMaster and I did convert a text field into a MC but I did not give a/the text field inside it a name. Apologies for my vagueness on this its been a long time since I have used AS3 with Flash and I am trying to remember it.